# countEdges in oriendb embeded javascript function

Tags: orientdb

I have a function that embeds JavaScript here

```
var gdb = orient.getGraph();
var retour = {};
try{
  var login = gdb.getVertex(id);
  if(login){
// ----- insert controle here -------
    var pays = login.getLabel().slice(-2);
    var Ccompte = gdb.getVertexType("Compte_".concat(pays))|| gdb.createVertexType("Compte_".concat(pays),"Compte");
    var Cconfig = gdb.getVertexType("Config_".concat(pays))|| gdb.createVertexType("Config_".concat(pays),"Config");  
    var compte = gdb.addVertex("class:"+Ccompte);
      compte.setProperty("Pays",pays);
    var config = gdb.addVertex("class:"+Cconfig);
      config.setProperty("Nom","message");
      config.setProperty("Desc","Service Messagerie");
    login.addEdge("Membre",compte)
    login.addEdge("MP", config );
    gdb.commit();

    retour.ID =  compte.getId();
    retour.pays = pays;
  }  
  else{
    retour.err = 'Compte Introuvable';
    retour.errcode = 152;
  }
} catch(err) {
  gdb.rollback();
  retour.err = err.toString();
  retour.errcode = 201
} finally {
  gdb.shutdown();
}
return retour;
```

and I am a control insert the number of Edges with

```
if ( login.countEdges (Direction.OUT, "Membre")== 0 ) {.....
```

Here is the description of countEdges

```
public long countEdges(Direction iDirection,String... iLabels)   (Blueprints Extension) Returns the number of edges connected to the current Vertex.

    Parameters:
        iDirection - The direction between OUT, IN or BOTH
        iLabels - Optional labels as Strings to consider
    Returns:
        A long with the total edges found
```

I have an error on the type Direction
 (error = "ReferenceError: \"Direction\" is not defined" )

if someone has an idea I'm interested

Thank you

Comment: can you post the error?

Comment: Are you getting this error "ReferenceError: \"Direction\" is not defined" ?

Comment: Error is "ReferenceError: \"Direction\" is not defined" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try substituting

```
if ( login.countEdges (Direction.OUT, "Membre")== 0 ) {.....
```

with

```
var edge=login.getRecord().field("out_Membre");
if(edge==null || edge.size()==0){ ...
```

Comment: it works with this code I'll do like that
Thank you very much for your help ...

it is amazing that the whole method of blueprints bookstore not use the "Direction" works fine in JavaScript! ... there probably has a solution, it would be interesting to find